# How to handle the static dropdowns of PASSENGERS field of https://www.spicejet.com/ using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriver, webdriverwait

Am practicing on Spice jet site to automate.Here am giving code what i have wrote.

```
package NewPackage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class HandlingStaticDropdowns 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
  {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\SeleniumJars\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriverdriver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");
    Select s = newSelect(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_Adult")));
    s.selectByValue("3");
    s.selectByIndex(6);
    s.deselectByVisibleText("5");
  }
}
```

Am not getting proper output. Please help me out and let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: Update the question with the manual steps you are trying to automate.

Answer (score 0):

The **PASSENGERS** field contains of 3(three) [dropdowns](/questions/tagged/dropdowns), one for the number of *Adult*, one for the number of *Child* and the other for the number of *Infant*. To select **5** for *Adult*, **3** for *Child* and **1** for *Infant* you need to to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  public class A_demo 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
          options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options); 
          driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#divpaxinfo"))).click();
          Select selectAdult = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#divpaxOptions div.passengers-wrap2 p>select[name$='_Adult']"))));
          selectAdult.selectByVisibleText("5");
          Select selectChild = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#divpaxOptions div.passengers-wrap2 p>select[name$='_Child']"))));
          selectChild.selectByVisibleText("3");
          Select selectInfant = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#divpaxOptions div.passengers-wrap2 p>select[name$='_Infant']"))));
          selectInfant.selectByVisibleText("1");
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: spicejet_passengers]